# Swift UITableView disappears after loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently experiencing an issue where when I create a UITableView via IB and display it. The UITableView loads fine to start with, it shows my 4 cells and then just disappears immediately.

I believe the tableview is just disappearing as the container view background can be changed and is still present.

I am loading the UITableView from storyboard after a tap into a UISearchBar which is embedded into the UINavigationBar.
I then insert it into a container. The container is then displayed on screen with the UITableView.

It is called with the following:

```
var searchFestivalTableViewContainer: UIView?

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    showSearchView()
}

func showSearchView() {

    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    // Setup the festival search controller inside the container

    searchFestivalTableViewContainer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 64, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height-64)))
    searchFestivalTableViewContainer!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()


    let searchFestivalTableController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchFestivalTableViewController") as? searchFestivalTableViewController

    searchFestivalTableController!.festivalList = allFestivals!

    searchFestivalTableViewContainer!.addSubview(searchFestivalTableController!.view)

    self.view.addSubview(searchFestivalTableViewContainer!)

}
```

The code for the class is:

```
class searchFestivalTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var festivalList: [Festival]?

struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [Festival]!
}

var allFestivals = [Objects]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    allFestivals = getFestivals()

    tableView.reloadData()

}

func getFestivals() -> Array<Objects> {

    var festivalSearchResult  = [String: Array<Festival>]()

    festivalSearchResult["Results"] = [Festival(// Hiding data structure)]

    var objectArray = [Objects]()

    for festival in festivalList! {

        festivalSearchResult["Results"]!.append(festival)

    }

    let sortedFestivals = festivalSearchResult.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }

    for (key, value) in sortedFestivals {
        objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
    }


    return objectArray
}



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return allFestivals.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allFestivals[section].sectionObjects.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    let sectionHeader = allFestivals[section].sectionName

    return sectionHeader

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let festivalInfo = allFestivals[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchFestivalTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! searchFestivalTableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = festivalInfo.festivalName

        return cell


    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        // Nothing to do here yet

    }

}

class searchFestivalTableViewCell: UITableViewCell  {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Here is the current output after the tableview flashes up and goes

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS2oz.png)

Please can you help assist why the tableview is just going?
There are no errors or information in the console.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should add your **searchFestivalTableViewController** as a `childViewController` to your first `view controller`, before you add its `view` as a `subview`. Not sure about it though, but that is the way I would try to accomplish it. More information here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: You are exactly right. If you don't do this, the view controller won't know that it's view is being sized and handled by another controller, and will still try adjust the frame and position it.

Comment: Fantastic! This worked a dream.
    self.addChildViewController(searchFestivalTableController!)
        self.view.addSubview(searchFestivalTableViewContainer!)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a UIViewController, you should instead use UITableViewController, as it includes all the stuff you want from the get-go.

To fix your issue however, try setting tableView.dataSource = self and tableView.delegate = self

Comment: oh and your hamburger menu icon is probably weird because you didn't include an `@2x` and `@3x` version of it. You should include that in your project to get the sizing right.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I had tried both dataSource and delegate via code and IB with no success. Also the hamburger looks fine on device, I just resized my screenshot a bit before uploading :)

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you are doing but I solved a somewhat similar problem by adding.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.tableView.reloadData()


}
```